# List tables involved in a sql statement before it is run?

Tags: .net, sql, executereader

Is it possible, in .NET, to pass a sql statement to SQL server for parsing and return the tables involved in the statement and the type of operation. So for a statement like this :

```
select * from Table1
left outer join Table2 on Table1.id=Table2.foreignid;
delete from Table2 where date < 2009/12/12
```

SQL Server might return the tables involved like this :

```
Table1    Read
Table2    Read
Table2    Delete
```

So the statement isn't executed, it just returns the tables involved.

The reason I ask is that the application I am working on has application level table permissions that I want to apply on a table by table basis. The current method of parsing out the tables involved in a statement uses a regular expression and fails in anything other than simple statements. Obviously you can't really be using a regular expression for this kind of job

Comment: ummm.... aren't your tables listed right there?

Comment: Of course they are but the point is I want parse out the tables in a reliable way that scales with complex sql queries. My example was deliberately simple as it should be. Since SQL Server must parse a sql statement as part of the execution process I am wondering if it can be instructed to return the tables involved in the statement rather than execute it

Comment: Why do it yourself? Why not simply use database-level permissions? That's what they were made for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would [SET SHOWPLAN_ALL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259203%28SQL.80%29.aspx) do it for you? It simulates the call query on the server and you may be able to parse the results.

Edit: It looks like [SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259226%28SQL.80%29.aspx) would be easier to parse.

Comment: The output is complex and is in XML (or maybe a variant call will return XML?)  This should work, but it'd probably be a lot of work.

Comment: Ah this is excellent, it's all there. From my first look I just need to parse the DefinedValues column in the result and parse out the columns involved in the query using the comma seaprator. And also I need to use the Type column which tells me the operation such as SELECT or DELETE.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

> The reason I ask is that the application I am working on has application level table permissions that I want to apply on a table by table basis.

It seems to me you should create a database level role to capture those permissions, and apply them on that level. You paid for your database management system - don't spend your time coding what is best done by a solution that's already in place.

Application level permissions may make sense on the row level, and even those can be implemented at the database. But if they are on the table level, I don't see any excuse that justifies coding enforcement yourself. Use your database, you paid for it.

Comment: You are absolutely right and I wish it was already like this. There is only one SQL login in the application I inherited, and the application manages users itself in the same database so it can apply application level permissions. Before I go with the SHOWPLAN solution I will look into whether I can assign roles to the sql user on the fly at application login (this is a web app). I can't get rid of the application level user system, so I might have to tether SQL logins to an application login. Thanks a lot Roland

Comment: Marked SHOWPLAN as solution for now, this may change

Comment: Fair enough Gaz Newt. I hope you manage to do what you need to do with the SHOWPLAN solution.